# Is it bad practice to create kafka producer in thread based on demand

Tags: java, multithreading, api, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We have a requirement where if a user posts a messages through API, we have to post that message to kafka topic. I am creating a new kafka producer ever time a request comes.

If there are multiple users making the API call, we will have multiple threads and multiple producers getting created. Is that bad practice. Should I change my logic.

Comment: If it's any help, the KafkaProducer javadoc says: "The producer is thread safe and sharing a single producer instance across threads will generally be faster than having multiple instances. "

Comment: In general the producer should be reused.  You can imagine the overhead in creating one every time in addition to what @KevinBoone has mentioned. Is there a reason why you need to create a producer for each request?